# Eclipse Link Multitenancy not working

Tags: spring-boot, eclipselink, multi-tenant, spring-test

Eclipse Link Multitenancy is not working properly.

Example Entity (the schema is being created by liquibase):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ENTITIES")
@Multitenant(MultitenantType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@TenantDiscriminatorColumn(name = "TENANT_ID", contextProperty = "eclipselink.tenant-id")
public class EntityClass
```

To set the multitenancy property on entity managers I use an aspect, like following:

```
@Around("execution(* javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory.*(..))")
public Object invocate(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    final Object result = joinPoint.proceed();

    if (result instanceof EntityManager) {
        EntityManager em = (EntityManager) result;

        final String tenantId = TenantContext.getCurrentTenantId();
        LOG.debug("Set EntityManager property for tenant {}.", tenantId);
        em.setProperty(EntityManagerProperties.MULTITENANT_PROPERTY_DEFAULT,
                tenantId);

        return em;
    }

    return result;
}
```

When I start the Spring Boot application this works perfectly. To have tenant information available during integration tests, I defined an annotation:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface AsTenant {
    String value();
}
```

To bind this value, I use a `TestExecutionListener`:

```
@Override
public void beforeTestMethod(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
    final Method testMethod = testContext.getTestMethod();
    final AsTenant asTenantAnnotation = testMethod
            .getAnnotation(AsTenant.class);

    if (asTenantAnnotation != null) {
        TenantContext.setCurrentTenantId(asTenantAnnotation.value());
    }
}
```

By debugging I can clearly say that the `TestExectionListener` is called before any EM is created and that the property is properly set for the EMs. When persisting anything to the database, Eclipse Link does not set a value for the column.

Maybe anybody can help me out with this, I have no Idea why EclipseLink Multitenancy is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got it working. If anybody ever faces a similar problem, here is my solution to it.

If using transactions, the context property for the tenant discrimination has to be set *after* the transaction is started (http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/solutions/multitenancy002.htm).

```
EntityManager em = createEntityManager(MULTI_TENANT_PU);
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.setProperty(EntityManagerProperties.MULTITENANT_PROPERTY_DEFAULT, "my_id");
```

To realise this in Spring Boot/Data environment, I customized Spring's `JpaTransactionManager`. This stays in addition to the Aspect in the Question, since there is not Transaction for `SELECT` queries.

```
public class MultitenantJpaTransactionManager extends JpaTransactionManager {

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager#doBegin(java.lang.Object, org.springframework.transaction.TransactionDefinition)
     */
    @Override
    protected void doBegin(Object transaction, TransactionDefinition definition) {
        super.doBegin(transaction, definition);

        final EntityManagerHolder emHolder = (EntityManagerHolder) TransactionSynchronizationManager.getResource(getEntityManagerFactory());
        final EntityManager em = emHolder.getEntityManager();
        final String tenantId = TenantContext.getCurrentTenantId();

        if (tenantId != null) {
            em.setProperty(EntityManagerProperties.MULTITENANT_PROPERTY_DEFAULT, tenantId);
        }
    }
}
```

This is easily wired via JpaConfiguration:

```
/**
 * Configures Eclipse Link as JPA Provider.
 */
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@AutoConfigureAfter({ DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
public class JpaConfiguration extends JpaBaseConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Override
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new MultitenantJpaTransactionManager();
    }

    @Override
    protected AbstractJpaVendorAdapter createJpaVendorAdapter() {
        EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter();
        return adapter;
    }

    @Override
    protected Map<String, Object> getVendorProperties() {
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        properties.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.WEAVING, detectWeavingMode());

        return properties;
    }

    private String detectWeavingMode() {
        return InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver.isInstrumentationAvailable()
            ? "true" : "static";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Disclaimer: This does not answer the above query but provides an alternative.

Using bytecode instrumentation, I have created a java example on Multi-Tenancy (Table per Tenant) with Eclipse Link and Spring Data. This idea is chosen to utilize the complete power of Spring Data.

One can execute [MultiTenantTest](https://github.com/plummb/java-examples/tree/master/multitenant-jpa) to see it working.

The idea is open-sourced and is available at [Maven Central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bitbucket.swattu/jpa-agent)

Steps:

1.Include dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bitbucket.swattu</groupId>
    <artifactId>jpa-agent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

2.Create a class as shown below. Package, Class and method has to be exactly same.

```
package org.swat.jpa.base;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
public class EntityManagerFactoryListener {
    /**
     * This method is called by JPA Agent.
     *
     * @param entityManager the entity manager
     */
    public static void afterCreateEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        //Business logic to set appropriate values in entityManager
        final String tenantId = TenantContext.getCurrentTenantId();
        if (tenantId != null) {
            em.setProperty(EntityManagerProperties.MULTITENANT_PROPERTY_DEFAULT, tenantId);
        }       
    }
}
```

3.Add javaagent when starting java

```
-javaagent:{path-to-jpa-agent-jar}
```